# Can map_server load a new map at runtime after starting?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have my robot load a new map if it moves off of an existing map into another space. I know how to use the map_server node to load a map when it is started up, but can I then tell it to load a different map without having to stop and re-start the node? What is the best way to do this? I looked at the map_server wiki and I don't see any service for 'set_map' or 'load_map' or anything like that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222812/can-map_server-load-a-new-map-at-runtime-after-starting?/) by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of [PR #1303](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/1303), Navigation2 supports this.

---

Originally posted by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) with karma: 156 on 2020-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0